# Unable to open database file (code 14): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode

Tags: android, database, sqlite, pragma

Here is what I am doing in my DatabaseHelper class.

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASENAME, null, VERSION);
        context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASENAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String queryProductsAllData = "CREATE TABLE `"+TABLE_PRODUCTS+"` (\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_BRANDID                +"`\tINTEGER,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRODUCTID              +"`\tINTEGER,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRODUCTCODE            +"`\tINTEGER,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PIECESINCASE           +"`\tINTEGER,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRODUCT_STOCK_UNITS    +"`\tINTEGER DEFAULT 0,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRODUCTADDEDBY         +"`\tINTEGER,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_BRANDCODE              +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_BRANDNAME              +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME            +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRODUCTSHORTNAME       +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PIECENETVOLUME         +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRICEPOINT             +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_TRADEPRICEPERCASE      +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_TRADEPRICEPERPIECE     +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_RETAILPRICEPERPIECE    +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_SERVICECHARGEPERPIECE  +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_SPDSHOPPERPRICEPERPIECE+"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_JTAXPERCASE            +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_SPDPRICEPERCASE        +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRODUCTADDEDON         +"`\tTEXT,\n" +
                        "\t`"+COLUMN_PRODUCTSTATUS          +"`\tINTEGER\n" +
                        ");";
    db.execSQL(queryProductsAllData);

    }

 @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_PRODUCTS);
}
`
```

Here is the log I am getting.

```
 12-28 10:27:52.509    2672-2672/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 31278 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
12-28 10:27:52.509    2672-2672/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:31278: (24) open(/data/user/0/com.vergesystems.heartbeat/databases/Heart_Beat-journal) -
12-28 10:27:52.510    2672-2672/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 31278 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
12-28 10:27:52.510    2672-2672/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:31278: (24) open(/data/user/0/com.vergesystems.heartbeat/databases/Heart_Beat-journal) -
12-28 10:27:52.510    2672-2672/? E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) unable to open database file
12-28 10:27:52.512    2672-2672/? E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/data/user/0/com.vergesystems.heartbeat/databases/Heart_Beat'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:632)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:318)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:292)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:213)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:191)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:571)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:269)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
            at com.vergesystems.databases.ProductsTableHelper.<init>(ProductsTableHelper.java:29)
```

Comment: did you use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: yes I am using this permission.

Comment: problem is here `DATABASENAME`

Comment: What's the value of `DATABASENAME`?

Comment: I tried changing database name. but still the same issue. I tried to remove database from ada shell command, but still no success :(

Comment: its the database name 

`public static final String DATABASENAME = "Heart_Beat";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was wrong with my code. I was initialising TableHelper class in other helper classes' constructor and that was calling DatabaseHelper's onCreate again so that was making it lock the database.

Removed TableHelper initialisation from the other TableHelper's constructor and put it in method where it was needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
context.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASENAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

You're using `SQLiteOpenHelper` and it does the database file management for you.